# Do vmware vmids persist across an ESX restart?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

I have a 2 node VMWare cluster (Simplivity) which I am planning to do some hardware maintenance on (i.e. switching them off). Hence I would like to cleanly shutdown the VM guests and subsequently bring them back. There are quite a few guests running (~200) so doing this manually via vsphere will take rather a long time. This is somewhat compounbded by dependencies in the startup which requires startup to be ordered. I am therefore hoping to do this via the command line using....

```
vim-cmd vmcsv/power.shutdown <vmid>
...
vim-cmd vmcsv/power.on <vmid>
```

I ran a test case of stopping and starting a VM. Via the CLI, it worked a treat, but when I tried starting the VM via vsphere, VMware decided that to start it on the other node than it had previously been running on, and **assigned it a new vmid**.

While I can identify the vmids when the VMs are running, what will happen after I have restarted the ESX hosts? Will the vmids I captured previously still reference the VMs? Or do I need to find a different way of identifying VMs and starting them?

(I would ask HPE - but their advice the last 3 times I have contacted them has been disastrously wrong)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using low level commands like `vim-cmd` instead of something more comfortable like PowerCLI on a vsphere controlled cluster? With PowerCLI it would just be something like `$vms = get-vmhost host |get-vm |? { $_.powerstate -eq 'PoweredOn' }` to store the running vms in a variable, then you could run `$vms | stop-vmguest` to stop the VMS, do your maintenance and run `$vms |start-vm` to start them again. Or just migrate them on a different host.

Comment: Yes, there are several good reasons why I am not using powercli - but if you can suggest an alternate method which does not rely on powercli, I would be interested to hear about it.

Comment: (migrating to another host is not an option either)

Comment: I'd be very interested in the reason to not use PowerCLI, since this is exactly what PowerCLI is intended for. :) Also, why contact HPE and not VMware? Interesting question though, I'd never thought about vmids for automation before.

Comment: Another option would be to use vSphere Orchestrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that they persist across restarts of ESX, however they are not completely static. Although unique in a cluster they do change when the VM is migrated by DRS. So a safe way to start it up again (if you know the name and the vmid from a point in the past) is:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms  | grep '$VMNAME' | grep $VMID && vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on $VMID
```